# C programming how to print out structure's elements when its in another header file?

Tags: c, struct

So I have a struct in another header file

```
struct MyStackStruct{
    void **stk;
    void *el;
    int sizeStk;
    int top;
    int choice;
};

typedef struct MyStackStruct MyStack;
```

I call it s in main.

It's fine if I do something like `s->top = -1;` on another file.c and I can print it out simply by `printf("%d", s->top)`

But I can't find a solution on how to print out the same thing in main. Nothing I tried works. Help!

Edit1: To make it clear. In struct.h I have

```
struct MyStackStruct{
    void **stk;
    void *el;
    int sizeStk;
    int top;
    int choice;
};

typedef struct MyStackStruct MyStack;
```

then in main.c I define it as  `MyStack* s;`
and send it to another file with functions using

```
MyStack *sP = &s;
```

and then something like `push(sP);`

if in push or any other function I do something like `s->top = -1;` and `printf("%d", s->top)` it prints out -1. If i do the same printf in main.c it prints out random numbers.

Comment: you need to post more code, your problem is not clear.

Comment: Posted, hope its more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the struct definition in a header file `struct.h`, and include it in `main.c` with `#include "struct.h"`. This way the compiler will have the details of the struct when compiling `main.c`.

`MyStack* s;` defines `s` as a pointer to `MyStack`, so `&s` is if type pointer to pointer of `MyStack`, which is `MyStack**`. In that case you should just use `s` for the operation, like `push(s)`.

Also, you need to initialize the pointer before use it, you can use `malloc`:

```
s = malloc(sizeof(*s));
```

Comment: Not really what I asked for. I already did those things. I'm asking on how to print out information in main file

Comment: @Johnie78 oh I see, print is the same as you do it in file.c, just use `printf("%d", foo->top)`;

Comment: Doesn't work. If I use for example s->top = -1; in file.c and printf("%d", s->top) in it prints out -1, if I use the same printf in main.c it prints random numbers...

Comment: @Johnie78 I see, that's another problem, how is `s` defined?

Comment: In main.c its defined as MyStack* s;

Comment: @Johnie78 ok, please post more code so we can help to debug.

Comment: @Johnie78 good, also try to enable compiler warnings, it will help you catch such problems.